# Is it dangerous to change the default language page to be the x-default page?

Tags: seo, internationalization, multilingual, geolocation, rel-alternate

I haven't specify the x-default page yet. Instead of that the the baseurl of the website specified with `<link rel=alternative>` as the default language "Arabic".

Is it dangerous (I may lose PageRank, google indexing or something) if set the baseurl to be considered as the `hreflang="x-default"` page and let the Arabic language take another url like /ar. Still the baseurl shows Arabic content and still the page identical to /ar.

*Change from:*

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com" hreflang="ar"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/de" hreflang="de"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en" hreflang="en"/>
```

*To:*

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com" hreflang="x-default"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/ar" hreflang="ar"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/de" hreflang="de"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en" hreflang="en"/>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for this scenario?